# How to inject HTTP server in Nest 6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm correctly working on upgrading a project from Nest 6 and I can't figure out how to inject the currently used HTTP server instance into a class.

Previously, I've been using the `HTTP_SERVER_REF` from `@nestjs/core` like this:

```
@Inject(HTTP_SERVER_REF) private readonly httpServer: HttpServer
```

This constant doesn't seem to exist anymore. I have a few monkey-patch solutions in mind that would give me access to the HTTP server but I'm wondering: Is there a new, proper way to inject the HTTP server? I'm using the default `@nestjs/platform-express` package by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can inject `HttpAdapterHost` instead, see [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/http-adapter):

```
export class CatsService {
  constructor(private readonly adapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {}
}
```

Then you can access the http adapter via this property:

```
const httpAdapter = this.adapterHost.httpAdapter;
```

The library instance you can get with:

```
const instance = httpAdapter.getInstance();
```

Comment: The docs don't appear to have changed, but I'm struggling to get this working.  When trying to inject it into a provider, HttpAdapterHost isn't found and I get the `can't resolve dependencies` error.  (Other dependencies are injecting into the same provider fine.)  Has anything here changed in the meantime?

Comment: ...figured it out.  Both @nestjs/core and @nestjs/common export a class by this name, but only the one imported from core will inject properly.